# Flash Channels: Performance Benchmark

Tags: flash-channel

Did someone a performance benchmark for the flash channels?

I would like to use them in a low latency scenario. I looked into the Javascript Code for it. Seems like they using HTTP 1.1 with JSON serialization. Is that correct? If yes, it might be really slow.

My requirements: Client to Server Communication under 50ms. To and back. (10 - 20ms network latency). So the serializatio/deserialization should be not slower than 5ms.

As suggested I describe what I need:

We have a Client Client (A) and a Server (B). The Client and the server communicating over flash channels.

B send A a transaction which contains a message. (Zero transaction) A replies B with another transaction. These transaction is a bid on a auction. B can decline the transaction if another Client gave a higher bid. This process must be low latency to make sure that all bids are came in before the auction ends.

My requirement is that the message B to A and A to B is in best case less than 50ms. To make it possible for A to do calculations before it send the bid to B. We have a latency between A and B of 5 - 20ms. That means that the serialization/deserialization between A and B has to be less than 5ms.

I want to know if someone already created a benchmark of flash channels and if someone did how? What is the result of this benchmark?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify where exactly in the process you expect the deserialisation to happen / which step you are referring to exactly? Your question seems rather vague at this point.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX Better?

Comment: Way better indeed :)